# Plant growth non-linear lag response analysis

Tags: nonlinear-regression, biostatistics

My first post here. I am a plant biologist/ecologist particularly studying rare species in their natural environment. I am not a mathematical statistician, just an average user of standard routines. The subject of this inquiry is an obscure clonal species that grows small leafy stems from underground rhizomes when conditions suit. Individual stems can disappear for months to years and it is a classic example of a plant being rare because it is rarely seen. The aim is to get some insight into the most favorable sprouting conditions so that optimum survey times can be described/predicted. It is a plant that is often in proposed development paths.

[image]
The data consist of Time (12 months Jan - Dec), predictors Total Monthly Rainfall and Monthly Cumulative Growing Degree Days (GDD). Response is stem abundance recorded at the end of each month. There are five replicate sites at which stem abundance was recorded over one full year.

A plot of mean monthly abundance fairly closely follows a 6th order polynomial line of best fit. There will be a lag response by abundance to prior predictor variables and the task is to statistically describe the conditions that lead to peak abundance and lowest abundance. I have looked at the R package dlnm but haven't run the data because I am unsure of how I would interpret the output or whether it would be appropriate.

I would appreciate some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the placement! I have added a summary plot using mean monthly temperature as it closely followed GDD and one less set of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I am an agronomy student, but I don't have very good knowlegde about plant ecology. I don't know if maybe performing something  similar to a growth model could be useful here, in which case you could check this out: https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2011.00155.x

Maybe you could explain better why is that lag in the response going on, but I suppose there must be a way to statiscally assess it, which unfortunately I don't know.

Maybe you would also would like reading this: https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1111/gcb.13976 . It's a papper that talks about lag response in plant communities.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Rafael. I have fitted a Gompertz growth curve to germination data in another setting. The lag occurs because the underground rhizomes are triggered by environmental conditions to start sprouting but it takes time (maybe a month) for these stems to appear above ground.